# Using Selenium in Python Trying to identify the number of a particular button and then to click all of that button based on that number

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import re

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
   list = f.readlines()

for items in list:
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/util/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get(items)
   time.sleep(3)
   element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Show all')]").click();
```

website being used: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers

I am trying to get it so that I can count the number of a particular button class and then click them all based upon the number value (added picture of one): [image]

```
class='details-control js-details-toggle pointer-cursor btn collapse-toggle table-collapse-toggle js-collapse-toggle collapsed'
```

I got this to work, but it skips some of the buttons:

```
element2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='details-control js-details-toggle pointer-cursor btn collapse-toggle table-collapse-toggle js-collapse-toggle collapsed']")
for x in range(0,len(element2)):
    if element2[x].is_displayed():
        element2[x].click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Show all')]"))).click()
my_buttons=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='details-control js-details-toggle pointer-cursor btn collapse-toggle table-collapse-toggle js-collapse-toggle collapsed']")

print(f"Found {len(my_buttons)} buttons")

for button in my_buttons:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", button)
    button.click()
```

You will need these imports for `WebDriverWait` (which is the preferred option over `time.sleep`):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: depending on what the click action does (especially if it changes the DOM) you may get stale element errors.